# How to compare items with values of list of dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a output list of dicts:

```py
# outList
[{'Current NAV': 22, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Current NAV': 25, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Current NAV': 31, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Current NAV': 55, 'status': 'Rejected'},
 {'Current NAV': 65, 'status': 'Rejected'},
 {'Amount Requested': 50, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Amount Requested': 55, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Amount Requested': 60, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
 {'Amount Requested': 80, 'status': 'Rejected'},
 {'Amount Requested': 90, 'status': 'Rejected'}]
```

Above data contains info about the attribute i.e. `Current NAV` `Amount Requested`, its value and its status. I have a below input list of dict:

```py
# fieldValList
[{'name': 'Current NAV', 'value': 33},
 {'name': 'Amount Requested', 'value': 45}]
```

I have to compare the value of `Current NAV` and `Amount Requested` from `fieldValList` with `outList` so that I get the output of how many values from outList are closer to `Current NAV` value i.e. `33`. In this case it is `22, 25, 31` are closer to 33 while values `55, 65` are far from it and thus `Confirmed` status becomes `3/5` while `Rejected` becomes `2/5`. Similarly for `Amount Requested` `55, 65, 50` are closer to 45 while `80, 90` are far from it and thus `Confirmed` status becomes `3/5` while `Rejected` becomes `2/5`.

How I can proceed to build a logic for this?

Comment: what's the cutoff point for being "close"? also what's the expected output format? do you want to update `fieldValList` or do you want a new list?

Comment: @enke There is no cutoff point as such, if confirmed is closer than the output is confirmed, it rejected is closer than then output will be rejected.

Comment: You can't words like "closer" without specifying what "closer" is measured relative to... You say 22, 25, and 31 are "closer" to 33 and 55, 65 are far, but "closer" is completely ambiguous. I could just as easily say that 31 is the only "close" value and everything else would be considered "far". You need to define exactly what you mean by "close". Is it any value within 10, any value less than 33, or some other criteria?

Comment: It's no wonder that you can't "build a logic for this" -- there is no logic yet. You have an ambiguous expected outcome for which you have not explicitly defined the logic with which it can be produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Similarly for Amount Requested 55, 65, 50 are closer to 45 while 80, 90 are far from it and thus Confirmed status becomes 3/5 while Rejected becomes 2/5.

Does it mean you want to get fractions of 'status' from 'outList' for each name from 'fieldValList'? If so then this is a tip:

```
from fractions import Fraction

# note that the list has been mutated
outList =[
    {'Current NAV': 22, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
    {'Current NAV': 25, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
    {'Current NAV': 31, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
    {'Current NAV': 55, 'status': 'Rejected'},
    {'Current NAV': 65, 'status': 'Rejected'},
    {'Amount Requested': 50, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
    {'Amount Requested': 55, 'status': 'Confirmed'},
    {'Amount Requested': 80, 'status': 'Rejected'},
    {'Amount Requested': 90, 'status': 'Rejected'}]
fieldValList = [
    {'name': 'Current NAV', 'value': 33},
    {'name': 'Amount Requested', 'value': 45}]

for i in fieldValList:
    n = [j['status']=='Confirmed' for j in outList if i['name'] in j]
    print(f"name: {i['name']}, Confirmed: {Fraction(sum(n), len(n))}")

>>> out
'''
name: Current NAV, Confirmed: 3/5
name: Amount Requested, Confirmed: 1/2
```

Otherwise, you should, as already mentioned, define the criteria for what is considered as *"closer"*.